# Mirror modifier works incorrectly

Tags: modeling, mirror-modifier

Hellow! 
I've got the following problem with the mirror modifier: 
After applying the mirror, it kinda of duplicates an object. I've applied rotation, set origin to geometry or 3D cursor,turned off/on clipping, -  nothung changed. There are no dubbled verts; I checked. Could it be a bug, or am I doing something wrong? [image]

Comment: Hello, please share the object before your applied the modifier?

Comment: unlikely to be a bug, but, reading the question, we can't know the state of the object before the modifier is applied

Answer (score 2):

You can use Bisect function of the modifier if you want the intersecting part to be cut off:

[image]

Comment: Yep, just tied it out. Now it's working normally. Thanks a bucnh!

Comment: If the answer is helpful, consider accepting it as the solution or upvoting.